# Screen freezes after reboot

Tags: 18.04, freeze

I have a machine running UBUNTU 18.04 LTS with Nvidia-driver 430 already installed. After reboot, I see a purple screen for ~10 seconds, after which the screen becomes black and freezes. After I hit the power button to reboot, among others, the following message appears:

```
[FAILED] Failed to start User Manager for UID 121
See ‘systemctl status user@121.service’ for details’
```

After I run this command in terminal, after booting in recovery mode, the following messege appears:

```
User@121.serive – User Manager for UID 121
    Loaded: loaded (/lib/system/system/user@.service; static; vendor preset: enabled
     Drop-IN:   /lib/system/system/user@.service.d
        timeout.conf
Active:     inactive (dead)
```

What might be the problem?

Comment: Did you disable Secure Boot in BIOS?

Comment: Check out https://askubuntu.com/a/760935/471065 and the question it came from.